# Print info from two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Trying to print infomation from array now, and dont want to use manu foreach in foreach cycles. So interesting how to output data from this array

```
Array
(
[aM] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [iId] => 0
                [iTime] => 00
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [iId] => 1
                [iTime] => 11
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [iId] => 2
                [iTime] => 22
            )
    )

[aN] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [sName] => a
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [sName] => b
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [sName] => v
            )
    )
)
```

Like this, data from first array near data from second

```
0 a, 1 b, 2v
```

? Not like here, first we output all data from first, than from second

```
0 1 2 a b v
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do this with a [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/multipleiterator), which will iterate over both arrays easily:

```
// $array = your array from up there

$iter = new MultipleIterator;
$iter->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator( $array['aM']));
$iter->attachIterator( new ArrayIterator( $array['aN']));

foreach( $iter as $data) {
    list( $a, $b) = $data;
    echo $a['iId'] . ' ' . $b['sName'] . ',';
}
```

You can see from [this demo](http://3v4l.org/ovQte) that it prints (for PHP >= 5.3):

```
0 a,1 b,2 v,
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, you want to iterate over 'aM' and then find the respective item in 'aN'.

```
$sets = array();
foreach ($arr['aM'] as $key => $item) {
    $sets[] = $item['iId'] . ' ' . $arr['aN'][$key]['sName'];
}
echo join(', ', $sets);
```